# change an alias target python

Tags: python, alias, shortcut

I would like to change the target of an alias using python. do I have to download some external library to do this. I played around with aliases a bit and can't figure out any way to edit them without user input.

I'm using mac, python 2.6

Comment: To clarify: I assume you are talking about file aliases in Mac OS X?

Comment: For your application, could you use a symbolic link instead? These are much more easily manipulated in Python.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell it should be possible using PyObjC to get at the Mac's Foundation library. I think **NSURLBookmarkResolutionWithoutUI** is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

PyObjC was a good suggestion. I couldn't find a solution anywhere, but after asking an equivalent question, finally managed to create one. See my answer to my own question: [how to read, change, and write macOS file alias from python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48862093/)