# copying/moving MANY OSX alias (...files? paths?) in python

Tags: python, macos, alias

First a clarification that by "alias" I mean `finder > right click on file > create alias`, not `.bash_profile` stuff (are they the same? I don't know, I confess).

**My scenario**: I have a huge bunch of microscope scans, images taken at different positions, different focal depths, on different channels etc etc, all in one biiiiig folder.

Files are something along the line of `TILE0123_FOCUS0123_CHANNEL0123.tiff`. I would like to sort them in subfolders, but sometimesI need to group them by "same tile, same focus, all channels", sometimes "same focus, same channel, all tiles" and so on. My idea then was to leave the original files unsorted and **create all the needed types of grouping with aliases**.

The only previous post about python and osx alias paths I found is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48862093/how-to-read-change-and-write-macos-file-alias-from-python) but to be honest it seems way more complicated than I hoped. So I tried selecting all images manually, right-click-create-alias them all, and then use my copying script. **Notice that the copying script uses `shutil.copy()`**

**My problem**: what gets copied is no longer an alias but just a txt file :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...if rather than copying, I move (with `shutil.move()`), the problem is no more.

I guess knowing a bit more about aliases could have helped.

Comment: Is this the answer?

Comment: yes, I thought by choosing "answer your own question" in the post page it would automatically get marked as accepted. Now I can't accept it for another 2 days tho